# REST Call to pull data from Parent Site to Subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm currently trying to pull data to my sub-site from a list within the Parent site using SharePoint Designer 2013 workflows.

The current Response Code is merely saying "Forbidden" so I can understand that as being the 2013 Workflow doesn't have permission to access the list data through the Web Service.

I've enabled Workflows on both sites to be elevated and my current REST call has also been tested within an App Step but to no avail.

This is my current REST call:

[image]

This is the REST call that works fine in the browser, it lists all the available items in the list:

> mysite.com/parent/_api/web/lists/getbyid('d57af43f-5e5a-4783-bfdb-5a35656759fb')/items

The dictionary headers are the standard headers for Accept/Content-Type. I've also tried using the Authorization header.

[image]

My REST call settings are also as they should be:

[image]

What else do I need to allow me to access the Parent sites list data on my sub-site? Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the REST call that works fine in the browser, it lists all the available items in the list

The browser is using the authentication cookies from the browser, so it is working with your credentials. The workflow is by default using a service account.

You say you have added an App step. Did you go to the other site and configure app permissions? Did you use this URL as part of the process? http://{hostname}/{the Site Collection}/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

See this article for details on setting up the app permissions:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo

Comment: Yes Mike as i'd mentioned, i've setup elevated permissions on both sites for workflows but still the same forbidden Response Code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Authorization from your dictionary